# save multiple pages in favorite page based on cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies

hi I am designing a real estate website i have many ads in my website and when user click on a certain ad it goes to another page `viewmore.php` which gives user more details about that certain ad.
Now as you see in `viewmore.php` file I save ad's id in cookies and send ad's id to the favorite page and user can review that post any time he or she wants in favorite page.
now the problem
consider a user visit two post
`viewmore.php?id=10`
and
`viewmore.php?id=7`
in this case he or she wants to see both ads in favorite page not, only the last one. in my code it just shows the last add with `id=7` how can i change my codeso that previous add does not disappear. any idea? thank u
viewmore.php

```html
<?php
$ID = is_numeric($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : 1;

$cookie_name = "favoritepost";

if ( isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) {
    $kookie = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
} else {
    $kookie = array();
}
if ( ! in_array($ID, $kookie) ) {
    $kookie[] = $ID;
}

setcookie($cookie_name, serialize($kookie), time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$cookie_name = "favoritepost";
include("config.php");
if ( ! isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) {
    echo 'NO COOKIE SET';
    exit;
}

$kookie = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
$ID = $kookie[count($kookie)-1];
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE idhome = $ID");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result):
$price=$row['price'];
$rent=$row['rent'];
$room=$row['room'];
$date=$row['date'];

echo"price";
echo"room";
echo"date";
?>
```

Comment: Never ever serialize cookie data. Cookies are not safe from user manipulation and can lead to all kinds of nasty trouble and security vulnerabilities. Instead only ask if user has a cookie with valid values, and then build the object again if the cookie passes the validity checks.

Comment: @The Law thank you for your answering i did not get it could you please explain a little more or change my current code thanks